# Jupyter notebook error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datascience'

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, data-science

Good evening,
I am trying to import datascience module at my Jupyter notebook, but the notebook keeps showing error called

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-6f3a305c96af> in <module>()
----> 1 from datascience import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datascience'
```

although I have done

```
pip install --user datascience
```

Could anyone solve this problem for me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

first, check whether you have installed `datascience` package in to the same environment.

use `pip freeze` to list installed packages.

if it's installed correctly, then try this.

`import datascience as dt`

then you can access ant function in `datascience` package.

```
`dt.function()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these links can help you :
[link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-and-importerror-248ce5b69b1c), [link 2](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-modulenotfounderror/) and [link 3](https://www.hellocodeclub.com/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pygame/)

- First, activate your environment if you have it.
- Second, check your project path.
- Third, try to install your package one more time.
- Fourth, use freezing to check if a module is installed.
- Five, check if the import is well done.

Answer (score 0):

If ur using VS code

In the <>filename.ipynb file

Select kernel {Top Right} -> python environment -> choose the python which u have installed [/usr/local/bin/python3] (latest version)

check if the package datascience is installed using cmd `pip list`

at the start of the program `import datascience as dt`

Access it by `dt.anyfunction()`